# How to test if a file exists in javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, p5.js

So my website souly depends on the scripts and images that are on it, the issue is that all of that saves to the cache, so users aren't able to see my updates unless they clear their cache, or open in private browsing mode. I'm trying to make a system that checks to see if the cache needs to be cleared, and if so, automatically clearing it.

The way I thought of going about this is having a script in the html page that tests to see if "sketch1.js" exists, and if it doesn't, clearing the cache, and testing again. Then every time I update the 'sketch.js' file I'll add 1 to the number at the end of the name.

Please tell me what you think of my ideal solution, should I use a different method to clear my sites cahce? If not, how would I go about testing if the file exists?

Comment: Can't you set the cache policy of the files being served by your server?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, what's a cache policy? I'm kinda new to website hosting

Comment: @CameronSchoenecker: The web server's response includes headers (metadata). Some of those headers can tell the browser whether the content should be cached, and for how long.

Comment: Your server is what tells your browser how long to cache files. If you want to change how stuff is cached, you should generally change a setting on your server instead of trying to hack it with JavaScript on the client. I'd start with a google search of "cache policy" or looking through your server host's settings or documentation.

Comment: I think I get it, so what does this mean for my issue? Is it an easy fix?

Comment: oh! I'll do that

Comment: @CameronSchoenecker: It means you don't run code on the browser to loop through possible filenames. That way lies nothing but madness and despair. Rather, you configure your web server to set a shorter cache lifetime on the files in question.

Comment: @cHao thank you! I'll look into that.

Comment: Alright so I just contacted my hosting support and they're saying that they don't have the ability to edit my cache life time? In-fact they even told me to use java script to do it.

Comment: ...what the...? They don't have the *ability*? You better be getting free hosting, cause any host worth paying knows how to configure their effing web servers.

Comment: Alright, so any suggestions on how to solve my issue with javascript?

Comment: There's "window.location.reload(true);" which will reload the cache, but this issue is knowing when to call it

Comment: Like i said...madness and despair. Your best option is to have a separate loader script that knows the URL and tacks a randomly generated query string onto the end every time. But that basically means your main script will never be cached, and your pages may load visibly slower as a result.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering your questions about file checking (for knowledge purposes):**

I'm assuming here that you are using P5.js as per the post tags.

That being true, to test if an image exists you can use the [loadImage](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) function. That way you can try to preload the image to a variable and test if the object exists (check the P5 reference for code on how to do this).

As for testing a .js (or any other) file existance, you could either use [loadBytes](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadBytes) or [httpGet](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/httpGet) to try to load the file to a variable and, like in the image example, test if the object exists.

**Now for the caching issue:**

What you are trying to achieve here is basically "versioning". Like stated on the previous comments of the post, creating a whole check for this is quite painfull, may not work in some cases or even kill the cache benefits at all.

In fact, until recently javascript did not have the hability to clear cache (only a few browsers implements this and some people consider a security risk to expose this level of browser to the developer). Therefore even if you check for the files existence, you'll not be able to be guarantee across all browsers 100% of caches cleared.

One approach for you would be to version the folders of the files, instead of the files itself. For example, each "new version" of your "script.js" would have urls like these:

```
http://yoururl.com/scripts/1.0.0/script.js -> Version 1.0.0
http://yoururl.com/scripts/2.0.0/script.js -> Version 2.0.0
http://yoururl.com/scripts/3.1.0/script.js -> Version 3.1.0
```

Allying that with how the browsers handles cache of the .HTML file, you can have the cache benefits for the assets (js, images, etc) on your page while their folder version is not changed on the base .HTML files.

To achieve that, if you are using static HTML pages, the web server will automatically add the "Last Modified" header to your pages, allowing the browser to check if the last cached .HTML file is still the same. If no changes were detected, it will load the .HTML file from cache, else it will load the new .HTML from server. However, if your pages are dynamic, then you'll have to add the "Last Modified" header programatically.